# Under what conditions on Unix can gtk_file_chooser_get_filename() return NULL signifying a non-local filename?

Tags: unix, gtk

From the documentation for `gtk_file_chooser_get_filename()`:

> The currently selected filename, or `NULL` if no file is selected, **or the selected file can't be represented with a local filename**. Free with `g_free()`.

Is there at least one situation where the bolded condition is true on a Unix system (Linux, the various BSDs, etc.)? I tried reading through the source code but got lost/confused. I'd like to know so I can determine if I need to handle it in some special way; I don't need to know every possibility for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't yet read through the source either, but I would guess that `gtk_file_chooser_get_filename()` essentially returns `g_file_get_path (gtk_file_chooser_get_file (...))`. Probably the only case in which you would need to care about the filename being `NULL` is if your file chooser is enabled to pick files from a network share, for example. It's probably not something you need to worry about if you set the [`local-only`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#GtkFileChooser--local-only) property on your file chooser.

However, it's probably good practice to use `gtk_file_chooser_get_file()` anyway, since you will transparently be able to handle non-local files if you have the proper GVFS modules installed.

Comment: Do you know a way I can reproduce such a networking situation? I'm sending the filename to another runtime entirely so I can't use gio here, alas :/ I can tell you from what I did read of the code is that IS how it gets the filename out.

Comment: I think the point that function is trying to make is that it will return NULL in the case that the file can't be represented with a filename. So in that case, you wouldn't be able to send it to your other runtime anyway. I would suggest using `local-only` -- in that case NULL should not even be a possibility -- or modifying your other program to accept a URI instead of a path, and use `g_file_get_uri()`.